# Incorrect fragment height in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview

Tried to reproduce Roomorama's nice Availability page, with multiple, scrollable Caldroid fragments:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kpb8435ffv1psp/Screenshot_2013-08-26-18-17-53.png

If I add multiple Caldroid fragments to a LinearLayout that's fine, no problem at all. BUT if I embed it into a ScrollView, height will be messed, and I'll get this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3ntnkrnr8shbbv/Screenshot_2013-08-26-17-57-54.png

layout/date_chooser.xaml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

src/.../DataChooser.java

```
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.date_chooser);

    ArrayList<CaldroidFragment> caldroidFragments = new ArrayList<CaldroidFragment>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        caldroidFragments.add(buildCaldroidFragment());

    FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    for (CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment2 : caldroidFragments)            
        t.add(R.id.root, caldroidFragment2);

    t.commit();
}
...
```

Here you can find the relevant code snippet:
https://gist.github.com/gabororosz/6343558

Do you have any idea, or workaround?

Thank you!

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Layouts used in fragments should have height set to wrap content.

Comment: That does not help at all, measurement of view height is incorrect.